# mysql select recursive parent id error Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I am beginner and I try to implement a recursive query based on parent_id.

I have found a example that working good in a old answer:

the table is :

```
create table department (id int, name varchar(100), id_parent int null);
insert into department values (1, 'DEPARTMENT 1', NULL);
insert into department values (2, 'DEPARTMENT 2', 1);
insert into department values (3, 'DEPARTMENT 3', 2);
insert into department values (4, 'DEPARTMENT ABCD', 3);
insert into department values (5, 'DEPARTMENT X', NULL);
insert into department values (6, 'DEPARTMENT Y', 5);
insert into department values (7, 'DEPARTMENT Z', 6);
insert into department values (8, 'DEPARTMENT AB', 7);
```

and the query:

```
SELECT D2.id, D2.name, D2.id_parent
FROM (
    SELECT
        @d AS _id,
        (SELECT @d := id_parent FROM department WHERE id = _id) AS id_parent,
        @l := @l + 1 AS level
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            @d := (select id from department where name like 'DEPARTMENT AB'), 
            @l := 0
        ) initial_level,
        department D
    WHERE @d <> 0
) D1
JOIN department D2 ON D1._id = D2.id
ORDER BY D1.level DESC;
```

I have selected that example because it have also a working demo here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f182fb/4

**THE PROBLEM :**
So online in sqlfiddle that working good but if I have tried them in my PC got this error:
*Unknown column '_id' in 'where clause'*

I running on WAMP with mysql5.7.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved them using @d variable instead _id.

```
(SELECT @d := id_parent FROM department WHERE id = @d) AS id_parent
```